# Create dynamic worksheet variable

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have a list with following data:

```
month = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr" ]
```

Each month's data is stored in JSON like:

```
[{"Master" : [
        {
           "month" : "Jan",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "1"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Jan",
           "Expense" : "500",
           "Income" : "1000",
           "Emp" : "2"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Feb",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "1"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Feb",
           "Expense" : "500",
           "Income" : "1000",
           "Emp" : "2"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Mar",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "2"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Apr",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "1"
        }
     ]
}]
```

Depending on the value of `month`, I need to write all the content of each month's data to separate sheets with names "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr" etc using a `for loop`, something like:

```
for i in range(len(month)):
    worksheet[i] = workbook.add_worksheet(month[i])
```

The content in the list `month` is subject to change and hence the dynamic variable allocation required.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Why don't you try it, before asking?

Comment: I am getting an error on `workbook.close()` as `SyntaxError: invalid Syntax`.

Comment: Then you should add the code you are using, the error that you are getting, in the quesiton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you are looking for. You can configure which columns and months are required:

```
import xlsxwriter
import itertools

data = [{"Master" : [
        {
           "month" : "Jan",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "1"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Jan",
           "Expense" : "500",
           "Income" : "1000",
           "Emp" : "2"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Feb",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "1"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Feb",
           "Expense" : "500",
           "Income" : "1000",
           "Emp" : "2"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Mar",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "2"
        },
        {
           "month" : "Apr",
           "Expense" : "50",
           "Income" : "100",
           "Emp" : "1"
        }
     ]
}]


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')

# List of required months
months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Apr" ]    

# List of required columns and required order
columns = ['month', 'Expense', 'Income', 'Emp'] 

for workbook_month in months:
    for data_month, g in itertools.groupby(data[0]['Master'], key=lambda x: x['month']):
        if workbook_month == data_month:
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(workbook_month)
            worksheet.write_row(0, 0, columns)

            for row, entry in enumerate(g, start=1):
                worksheet.write_row(row, 0, [entry[col] for col in columns])

workbook.close()
```

Giving you the following output, here I have missed out the `Mar` data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin. That helped.